# BertForSequenceClassification vs. BertForMultipleChoice for sentence multi-class classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I'm working on a text classification problem (e.g. sentiment analysis), where I need to classify a text string into one of five classes.

I just started using the [Huggingface Transformer](https://huggingface.co/transformers/index.html) package and BERT with PyTorch. What I need is a classifier with a softmax layer on top so that I can do 5-way classification. Confusingly, there seem to be two relevant options in the Transformer package: [BertForSequenceClassification](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html#bertforsequenceclassification) and [BertForMultipleChoice](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html#bertformultiplechoice).

**Which one should I use for my 5-way classification task? What are the appropriate use cases for them?**

The documentation for **BertForSequenceClassification** doesn't mention softmax at all, although it does mention cross-entropy. I am not sure if this class is only for 2-class classification (i.e. logistic regression).

> *Bert Model transformer with a sequence classification/regression head on top (a linear layer on top of the pooled output) e.g. for GLUE tasks.*
>
> - ***labels** (torch.LongTensor of shape (batch_size,), optional, defaults to None) – Labels for computing the sequence classification/regression loss. Indices should be in [0, ..., config.num_labels - 1]. If config.num_labels == 1 a regression loss is computed (Mean-Square loss), If config.num_labels > 1 a classification loss is computed (Cross-Entropy).*

The documentation for **BertForMultipleChoice** mentions softmax, but the way the labels are described, it sound like this class is for multi-label classification (that is, a binary classification for multiple labels).

> *Bert Model with a multiple choice classification head on top (a linear layer on top of the pooled output and a softmax) e.g. for RocStories/SWAG tasks.*
>
> - ***labels** (torch.LongTensor of shape (batch_size,), optional, defaults to None) – Labels for computing the multiple choice classification loss. Indices should be in [0, ..., num_choices] where num_choices is the size of the second dimension of the input tensors.*

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer to this lies in the (admittedly very brief) description of what the tasks are about:

> [`BertForMultipleChoice`] [...], e.g. for RocStories/SWAG tasks.

When looking at the [paper for SWAG](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.05326.pdf), it seems that the task is actually learning to *choose from varying options*. This is in contrast to your "classical" classification task, in which the "choices" (i.e., classes) *do not vary* across your samples, which is exactly what `BertForSequenceClassification` is for.

Both variants can in fact be for an arbitrary number of classes (in the case of `BertForSequenceClassification`), respectively choices (for `BertForMultipleChoice`), via changing the `labels` parameter in the config. But, since it seems like you are dealing with a case of "classical classification", I suggest using the `BertForSequenceClassification` model.

Shortly addressing the missing Softmax in `BertForSequenceClassification`: Since classification tasks can compute loss across classes indipendent of the sample (unlike multiple choice, where your distribution is changing), this allows you to use Cross-Entropy Loss, which factors in Softmax in the backpropagation step for [increased numerical stability](https://medium.com/@zhang_yang/understanding-cross-entropy-implementation-in-pytorch-softmax-log-softmax-nll-cross-entropy-416a2b200e34).

Comment: Thank you. In sentiment analysis, the problem is that given a sentence, the classifier should predict a label from a set of non-changing labels (e.g. `pos`, `neg`, or `neutral`) . In RocStories and SWAG, the problem is that given a sentence, the classifier should choose one of several sentences that best logically follows the first. Here, the set of labels could be a small, non-changing set as well (e.g. `A`, `B`, `C`). I don't want to overthink the problem, so I'll use `BertForSequenceClassification` in my case.

Comment: Just a note, you can change the classification layer of both like [this](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/1001).